# EMC (radiated emission test) issue in buck converter

Tags: buck

i am designing CV smps 12V 1A (with EMC design) post that output side i will use dc to dc buck (Vin-12V Vout-9V, 400mA) or Boost convreter (Vin- 12V VOut-36v, 100mA). which configuration will be more suitable considering don't need to add EMC component in both)

Comment: It is required if you intend to sell the product, as you must make sure it doesn't cause harmful interference.

Comment: For the most part, the secondary converter should only cause radiated emissions.  The primary can cause both radiated and conducted.  The secondary is usually prevented by the primary from conduction issues.  All these are "usually" because it depends on your design and layout.

Comment: @Aaron thanks .what will effect if i use 12v to 36V boost converter with 420KHz ?